# Programmatically shutdown application before webtest

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, webtest

How can I shutdown web application before each webtest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Create a web test plugin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243191(VS.80).aspx) that will give you the ability to run code before the webtest runs.